# SQL Server 2008 R2 - How to use a production database through dev/test environments or how to copy a SQL schema and all its data to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, development-environment, production-environment, erp

We currently have 3 Windows Server 2008 R2 VM identically build for Sage x3, one for production/formation/budget database, a second one for QA (qualification) and a third one for dev & tests. This makes a total of 6 databases.

We would like to improve our process in order to always have fresh production data in dev, test and qualification (and potentially review, at the same time, the budget and training databases locations, which are also copies of the production scheme).

As I'm not a database specialist (currently an infrastructure engineer apprentice), let alone Microsoft SQL Server... I come to ask you for advice and best practices. Our infrastructure being rather modern, robust and spacious, we don't have any storage capacity or performance problems but, in the interest of optimization, I would like to avoid, as much as possible, having to duplicate 6 times the production VM (about 800 Go) or the production database as it is more or less the case actually...

So is there a way to use the production database from another environment but to redirect the writings of those environments to another location, specific to each environment (another schema or somewhere else...) to keep production database clean as it should be, exactly as a VM snapshot does physically (redirect on write) ?
If not, I think I will have to copy the database 6 times (don't hesitate to tell me if I'm wrong)... How could I proceed in SQL Server 2008 R2 because it's hard to find how to copy tables (and their data) from a specific schema to another database schema on another server and to automate it.

And, afterwards, is it possible to do differential copy (each night for example) to reduce the process duration.

Thanks a lot for all your answers :)

Sincerely yours,
Tigerblue77

Comment: Stack Overflow certainly isn't the right place for this question, however, this could also be too broad for [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: *On a different note, I **assume** you're aware that all the technology you've listed above is **completely** unsupported, right?*

Comment: Hello Larny, thanks for your prompt answer, I'll repost my topic on those forums.
Yep I know but, do you want to tell my boss ? :P
Little additionnal question, are MS SQL Server updates free ?

Comment: Express is free, updating your version for a paid version is not free.

Comment: I already have paid version so it's free ? :)

Comment: What part of **not** free was unclear? ;)

Comment: "Our infrastructure being rather modern, robust and spacious" - modern? we are in 2020 - latest version of SQL Server is 2019 - and the version you're working on ended it's extended support last year - so I wouldn't exactly call that modern. What next? hope you're not working on windows NT servers...

Comment: Larnu, my bad English is not my main language ;)
Zohar Peled, I was talking about our infrastructures, not the VM and apps that we run on it :)